# Why isn't the User information appending the mysql database using django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am having issues with a django-ajax project in which whenever I try to register a user, it does not append the user information to the mysql database and instead I get this in the terminal when I run the server:

```
Not Found: /sign-up/ajax-sign-up 
[Time of request] " POST /sign-up/ajax-sign-up HTTP/1.1" 404 2430
```

Furthermore, I get this error that does not go away on VScode regarding the User class on the forms.py:

```
Class 'User' has no 'objects' member
```

I have added the pylint add-on to remove the error assuming is the Class 'User' error is the issue and I have rewriting the views.py but nothing has worked.

Here is my forms.py script:

```
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
    from django.db.models import F
    from project.models import User
    from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from random import randint

import json, re

class Ajax(forms.Form):

    args = []
    user = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        if len(args) > 1:
            self.user = args[1]
            if self.user.id == None:
                self.user = "NL"

    def error(self, message):
        return json.dumps({ "Status": "Error", "Message": message }, ensure_ascii=False)

    def success(self, message):
        return json.dumps({ "Status": "Success", "Message": message }, ensure_ascii=False)

    def items(self, json):
        return json

    def output(self):
        return self.validate()

class AjaxSignUp(Ajax):

    def validate(self):
        try:
            self.username = self.args[0]["username"]
            self.password = self.args[0]["password"]
            self.email = self.args[0]["email"]
        except Exception as e:
            return self.error("Malformed request, did not process.")

        if not re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$', self.username):
            return self.error("Invalid username, must be fit [a-zA-Z0-9_]")
        if not re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$', self.email):
            return self.error("Invalid email syntax.")
        if len(self.username) < 4 or len(self.username) > 20:
            return self.error("Username must be between 3 and 20 characters long.")
        if len(self.password) < 6 or len(self.password) > 32:
            return self.error("Password must be between 6 and 32 characters long.")
        if len(self.email) < 6 or len(self.email) > 140:
            return self.error("Email must be between 6 and 32 characters long.")

        if User.objects.filter(username=self.username).exists():
            return self.error("Username already in use.")

        if User.objects.filter(email=self.email).exists():
            return self.error("Email address already in use.")

        u = User(username=self.username, password=make_password(self.password), email=self.email)
        u.save()

        return self.success("Account Created!")

class AjaxLogin(Ajax):
    def validate(self):
        try:
            self.password = self.args[0]["password"]
            self.email = self.args[0]["email"]
        except Exception as e:
            return None, self.error("Malformed request, did not process.")

        if not re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$', self.email):
            return None, self.error("Invalid email syntax.")
        if len(self.password) < 6 or len(self.password) > 32:
            return None, self.error("Password must be between 6 and 32 characters long.")
        if len(self.email) < 6 or len(self.email) > 140:
            return None, self.error("Email must be between 6 and 32 characters long.")

        if not User.objects.filter(email=self.email).exists():
            return None, self.error("Email or password is incorrect.")

        if not check_password(self.password, User.objects.filter(email=self.email)[0].password):
            return None, self.error("Email or password is incorrect.")

        u = User.objects.filter(email=self.email)[0]

        return u, self.success("User logged in!")
```

views.py script:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import User
from .forms import *
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout as dlogout

def ajaxsignup(request):
    ajax = AjaxSignUp(request.POST)
    context = {'ajax_output': ajax.output() }
    return render(request, 'ajax.html', context)

def ajaxlogin(request):
    ajax = AjaxLogin(request.POST)
    logged_in_user, output = ajax.validate()
    if logged_in_user != None:
        login(request, logged_in_user)
    context = {'ajax_output': output}
    return render(request, 'ajax.html', context)

def signup(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'sign-up.html', context)

def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index),
    path('sign-up/', views.signup),
    path('ajax-sign-up', views.ajaxsignup),
    path('ajax-login', views.ajaxlogin),
]
```

No matter what I try, I continue to get these errors:

```
Not Found: /sign-up/ajax-sign-up 
[Time of request] " POST /sign-up/ajax-sign-up HTTP/1.1" 404 2430
```

and User information is not appended to the database. The user information should be updated and I am sure that the I am calling the classes correctly.

I greatly appreciate your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand what you are doing in that Ajax class, but that class doesn't seem to be used anyway; you have AjaxSignup and AjaxLogin instead, which you haven't shown.

But nevertheless, your error doesn't even come from any of this code. As the message clearly says, you are requesting a URL that doesn't exist. You are requesting "/sign-up/ajax-sign-up", but your signup URL is just "/ajax-sign-up".

(And the warning from pylint is just that, a warning; you should ignore it. But, again, you aren't even using User anywhere in the code you have shown.)

Comment: My apologies, I updated/edited the rest of the code on forms.py script above. I am trying to call the class AjaxSignup to register the user and update the databases. Perhaps there is an issue with the ajax in the html page?

Comment: Well I told you what the problem is: you're posting to the wrong URL. What is unclear about that? (Although I can't imagine why you've written all that code bypassing and replicating what Django forms already do, but that is not the problem here.)

Comment: I found the issue. It wasn't a matter of being unclear as you said from your first response, the error was not from the code I posted in my question which is why I thought it could have come from the ajax in the html file. Regardless, you were correct and I fixed the issue by modifying the urlpatterns to path('sign-up/ajax-sign-up', views.ajaxsignup) in the urls.py code I posted. This registered the user information and fixed the issue. I am very grateful for your help and appreciate your time.